# wordpressでトップ画面以外が全て404エラーとなる

Tags: php, wordpress

wordpressのサーバーを移転した後に、移転先のサーバーでトップの画面は表示されるのですが、それ以外の全てのページは404エラーとなるようになってしまいました。

アクセスの少ない、深夜に作業していましたが、だいぶ時間が経っても解決できないため、質問させてもらいます。

サイトで紹介されている事は、ほとんど試していますがうまくいきません。

自分でも、解決できるよう調べながら作業しますが、対策についてご存じの方おりましたら、お力かしてもらえないでしょうか？

【エラーの状況】

- サーバー移転後よりエラーが発生
- ネームサーバは切り替え済み
- ドメインはSSL化で使用
- トップの画面は問題なく表示される（文字化け、レイアウトの崩れ無し）
  追記）新規の投稿はでき、一覧画面に表示されるが、それをクリックすると404エラーとなる
- 現在のパーマリンクの設定は、投稿名（https://sample.com/sample-post/）としており、エラーがでるが、基本（https://sample.com/?p=123）に変更すると、404エラーなく表示される

【これまでに行った対応】

- パーマリンクの設定の変更の保存
- .htaccessの内容の確認
- .htaccessの権限の変更 644 => 646
  [WordPressの引っ越し（移行）で404エラーが発生する場合の対処法](https://t-tel.net/wordpress/071/)
  [パーマリンク設定エラー「.htaccessを更新する必要があります。」の対処法](http://rigelstep.com/htaccess-1568)
- httpd.confコードの確認

[【WordPress】.htaccessもapacheの設定もバッチリなハズなのに意図しないページが404になってお手上げ状態の時](https://qiita.com/nnmr/items/ac7599b356f9bcb511cc)
httpd.confの一部コード

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

- httpd.confへのコードの追加

「Let’s Encrypt」を使ってSSLの再設定をする際に以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80.
```

そのため、/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.confに以下の内容を追記しています。
[SSL証明書を発行するときに出たエラーの対処法](https://hacknote.jp/archives/48748/)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin root@hogehoge
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName hogehoge
</VirtualHost>
```

このコードを追加してhttpsの表示ができるようになりました。
その後、色々設定等を行ってから、/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.confを再度見てみると

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@hogehoge
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName hogehoge
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =hogehoge
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    </VirtualHost>
    Include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf
```

というように、自分では追加していないコードが追加されていました。

【.htaccessのコード】

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN ブラウザキャッシュ
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On

    # キャッシュ初期化
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

    # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

    # RSS
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    # データはキャッシュさせない
    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Favicon
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

    # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

    # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/js                               "access plus 1 month"

    # マニフェスト
    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

    # 画像や動画
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

    # Webフォント
    # Embedded OpenType (EOT)
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"

    # OpenType
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"

    # TrueType
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 1.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 2.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"

    # Other
    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END ブラウザキャッシュ

# BEGIN Gzip圧縮
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

  # Mozilla4系などの古いブラウザで無効、しかしMSIEは除外
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

  # gifやjpg、pngなど圧縮済みのコンテンツは再圧縮しない
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI _\.utxt$ no-gzip
  #DeflateCompressionLevel 4

  # 有効な圧縮
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
</IfModule>
# END Gzip圧縮

# END WordPress
```

サーバー環境
CentOS (7 x86_64)
Apache (2.4.6 CentOS)
PHP (7.1.33)
wordpress(5.2.5)

Answer (score 0):

移転前に設定していたパーマリンク設定で、表示されるようになりました。
原因はhttpd.confのコードに不備があった事です。

質問欄の中では、ルートディレクトリの箇所のみ、オーバーライドを許可していましたが、それ以外のディレクトリも同様に許可する事が必要でした。

表示自体はされるようになりましたが、プラグインの更新時等に、ホストへの接続許可が出ない等、他のエラーがありますが、上の方法で今回の質問の404エラーは解決できました。